# JSON escaped characters

Tags: php, javascript, json, special-characters

I have a string that terminates prematurely because of '&q' (I'm guessing) being escaped in the original string. How should I handle this if I want to retain the original string in PHP?

Original string

```
'http://answers.onstartups.com/search?tab=active&q=fbi'
```

Result of var_dump

```
'["http://answers.onstartups.com/search?tab=active'
```

JS

```
var linksStr = $("#links").val();
var matches = JSON.stringify(linksStr.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/[^\s]+/gi));

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: 'matches=' + matches,
      url: 'publishlinks/check_links',
      success:                    
        function(response) {
        alert(response);

        }
    })
```

check_links

```
$urls = $this->input->get('matches');        
var_dump($urls);
```

Comment: Reposts are not appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044409/json-escaped-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `data: 'matches=' + matches,`

To: `data: {"matches": matches},`.

So that jQuery will figure out the encoding for you. Otherwise you'll have to encode the uri using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 3):

You can encode the JSON string:

```
    data: 'matches=' + encodeURIComponent(matches),
```

You could also write it like:

```
    data: { matches: matches }
```

and then jQuery should do the encode step for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your url as returned from jQuery .val() is:

```
'http://answers.onstartups.com/search?tab=active&q=fbi'
```

The `.match()` regex will return an array:

```
new Array("http://answers.onstartups.com/search?tab=active&q=fbi")
```

Which JSON.stringify() correctly outputs as:

```
["http://answers.onstartups.com/search?tab=active&q=fbi"]
```

However if you attach it as **raw** GET parameter here:

```
 data: 'matches=' + matches,
```

Then the enescaped `&` in the URL will terminate the GET value. Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%3aGlobal_Functions%3aencodeURIComponent)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about the repost :)